# DatePicker don't update selected date after ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker, popup

I have an issue with a datepicker selector on a popup. I load the datepicker with the required date, but when I make a requestto the server, the server response a date change. So I repopulate the datepicker with the new value, but the selected date on the date selector still have the old date. [See the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AT6m.png)

Here is my jQuery snippet:

```
 var beginDate = $('#ChDate').val();
    $('#Date').datepicker({
        autoclose: true,
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        defaultDate: beginDate,
        startDate: new Date()

    });
```

on my server response I have

```
 $("#Date").datepicker("setDate", result.Date);
```

on my page

```
<input id="ChDate" type="hidden" value="06/04/2016"/>
<input type="text" id="Date" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" readonly=""  required>
<button type="button">Update</button>
```

I tried to set the hidden value too and get it when the popup fires again but still the same problem. I tried too out of the popup and have the same behavior.

Comment: It's working for me, so one option could be that `result.Date` isn't in a `DD/MM/YYYY` format. could you check?

Comment: Yes, it is in `DD/MM/YYYY` format, but here on `$("#Date").datepicker("setDate", result.Date);` the `result.Date` must be a javascript `Date()` object? I'll try this and I let you know.

Comment: It didn't work. It takes some dates. others don't.

Comment: it would be great to see the ones which work and the ones that don't. ;) in the meantime try to remove this line`dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',`